# Length cannot be zero -Wix Installation Error

Tags: wix

I have created an msi using wix. It has custom actions for database, windows services etc. While running the installer it fires this error which i an unable to fix..

```
    Error 1001. Error1001:  Exception occurred while initializing 
    the installation:System.ArgumentException: String cannot have zero length
```

Comment: The error message comes from .NET. Windows Installer doesn't intrinsically use .NET. Therefore, it is a .NET custom action that is having the problem. WiX-provided custom actions don't use .NET. Therefore, we can't answer because we don't know anything about the custom action that is having the problem. Install the MSI [with logging](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/get_a_log.htm). It should tell you which custom action to delve into. The problem is likely to be missing data that the custom action needs so your authoring for that custom action is relevant, too.

Comment: thanks...logging helped a lot